# Executor pool not processing all items

Tags: java, executorservice

I need to perform some action 50 million items. I have written below code

```
 AtomicInteger failCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
 long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);

  List<String> allids = getItems();//50 million items from db

  log.info(getAction() + " Total items found: " + allids.size());

  allids.stream().forEach(s -> {
    es.execute(new MyRunnable(s, failCounter));
  });

  es.shutdownNow();
  try {
    if (!es.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
      System.out.println("Still waiting...");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Exiting normally...");
  log.info("counter: " + failCounter.get());

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String id;
    private final AtomicInteger failCounter;

    RollupRunnable(String id, AtomicInteger failCounter) {
      this.id = id;
      this.failCounter = failCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        //perform some action        
      } catch (Exception exception) {
        failCounter.getAndIncrement();
        log.error(
            "Error in calling " + getAction() + " for id: " + id + "  of :" + this.getClass()
                .getSimpleName(),
            exception);
      }

    }
  }
```

But executor exists after processing first 30 items.

Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: please show us getItems()

Comment: @Dylan. It is picked from db. It will be list with 50 million strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `es.shutdownNow();` use `es.shutdown();`

`shutDownNow()` halts the processing of all the tasks including the ones that are not even executed.

That's the reason why not all of the items are executed by the Executor framework.